# Uncaught ReferenceError: WeakMap is not defined

Tags: android, android-webview, tradingview-api

In Android Kitkat, I  am getting "Uncaught ReferenceError: WeakMap is not defined" error message on this files:

1. https://s.tradingview.com/static/bundles/embed/embed_events_widget.f6d951f2236fa624e17e.js
2. https://s.tradingview.com/static/bundles/embed/embed_tickerswidget.84fde921871ed98f3ff5.js
   (49)
3. https://s.tradingview.com/static/bundles/embed/embed_hotlistswidget.193b33cfb6bf1306960f.js
   (148)
4. https://s.tradingview.com/static/bundles/embed/embed_marketoverviewwidget.53a8682d9c0bd1e4350d.js
   (132)

Is there any fix to avoid this error? Thanks.